# Why does this JSF expression not work?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have a simple problem on .xhtml page. This expression is not working :-

```
<a href="Photos.jsf?albumId=#{item.albumId}&blogId=#{PhotoAlbumsCommonBean.blogId}">
 photos
</a>
```

I get this error :-

```
Error Parsing /Common/PhotoAlbums.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 20] The reference to entity "blogId" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

And this is causing some kind of error.

Comment: I was making the same mistake, but puzzling over my '&&' logical operator in javascript.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to encode the ampersand - `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: It doesn't work :(. Now the error is :-The reference to entity "ampblogId" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: Have you put the semicolon after the &amp?

Comment: Replace it with "&amp;" and it will work. The URL should be Photos.jsf?albumId=#{item.albumId}&amp;blogId=#{PhotoAlbumsCommonBean.blogId}

Comment: @Petar - you can use the backtick character to escape code in the Markdown editor

Comment: using &#38; (an xhtml code for ampersand character) is a safer option, i reckon!

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the # signs.

Try this. It fixes the problem with the JSP EL and having ampersands encoded in XHTML pages:

```
<a href="Photos.jsf?albumId=${item.albumId}&amp;blogId=${PhotoAlbumsCommonBean.blogId}">
 photos
</a>
```

Comment: @Nitesh What do you mean it disappears? Does the querystring just look like this: "?albumId=&amp;blogId=..."?

Comment: Hi Steven, your answer is also correct. Don't know which one to vote as correct and give points :p. But i think, $ is not meant for JSF. It is for JSP, though it works.

Comment: I guess the correct symbol to use depends if you want immediate or delayed variable expansion. Good point.